# nginx rewrite rules from main domain to subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In my nginx domain.cong , I wrote the following rewrite rules ... 
when a request hits the main domain ( with or without www) it shoudl redirect ot the blog subdomain , but it seems to be wrong ...

```
server {
....
##### Rewrite rules for domain.tld => www.domain.tld #####
if ($host ~* ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$) {
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.$host_without_www$1 permanent;
}

##### Rewrite rules for www.domain.tld => subdomain.domain.tld #####
if ($host ~* 'www\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$')  {
    set $host_without_www $1.$2;
    rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://subdomain.$host_without_www$1 permanent;
} 
...
}
```

The first rule is correct:
`domain.tld => www.domain.tld`
but not the second one giving only
`www.domain.tld =>  subdomain.`
should be
`www.domain.tld =>  subdomain.domain.tld`

Comment: Do you have only one domain (say, domain.tld) or many different domains, which should be redirected to their own subdomain ?

Comment: I have only one domain, but many different subdomains..  I understand that rewriting rules is not the best way to handle that ( even if it's running fine ) ..  I need to redirect  domain.tld to www.domain.tld and all subdomains.domain.tld to the subdomain directories

Answer (score 9):

Your setup seems a little overcomplicated, and it's not a best practice to match for $host in "if"'s.
If you have only one domain, it's simple:

```
server {
    # ...
    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    return 301 $scheme://subdomain.domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.tld;
    # ...
}
```

If you have many domains, setup is similar, just use regex and capture variables at server_name

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution , modifying the 2nd rewrite rule:

```
##### Rewrite rules for www.domain.tld => subdomain.domain.tld #####
if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
  set $host_without_www $1;
   rewrite ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.$host_without_www$1 permanent;
}
```

it seems to be running fine until then

Comment: still, it's not recommended. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html